# What is GraphQL and where it can be Used?

Tags: graphql

What is GraphQL and 
In which kind of application it can be Used?

```
var { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');

var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`);

var root = { hello: () => 'Hello world!' };

graphql(schema, '{ hello }', root).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: your question is refer to this project [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/) from facebook opensource, you can find any answers from its site

Answer (score 0):

**GraphQL** is a query language for APIs where you write queries using an object structure rather than a text string. **It gives clients the power to ask for exactly what they need from Database or services**. **And it will return only that data** nothing more and nothing less from a single endpoints.

It supports multiple languages like JavaScript, Java, PHP, RUBY, Python etc.

If clients need only name, So what REST APIs does that it will send that particular id for that name fields with route path. But **graphql will only use a single endpoint which will be "/graphql"**.

```
                     GraphQL (endpoint ==>> /graphql)
                                   ▼
                                 types
          ▼ ➳➳➳➳➳➳➳➳➳➳➳➳ ▼ ➳➳➳➳➳➳➳➳➳➳➳➳➳➳➳➳ ▼
       Mutation                  Query                        Subscription
          ▼                        ▼                               ▼
     use for CRUD             use for Fetch                   use to manage
     operations                   Data                        product/change 
                                                              notifications 
            ➳                   ➳                           
              ➳               ➳
                 ➳          ➳
                    ➳     ➳
                      Types
                  ➳         ➳
               ➳              ➳
      Resolver                     Schema
         ▼                           ▼
   write logic here          Generate your schema
   how to fetch data            What data fetch
```

GraphQL can be use for below places :-

1. Data Fetching.
2. Data Modification.
3. Generate files (csv, pdf etc)
4. APIs